# Backbone throwing collection[method] function error

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, collections, synchronization, fetch

i have been playing with Backbone, I am trying to learn how it works so I can create phonegap app using backbone. With version 0.9.9 all worked well, after upgrade to 0.9.10 it returns:

```
TypeError: collection[method] is not a function

   collection[method](resp, options);

backbone-0.9.10.js (line 821)
```

It seems that problem has something to do with following sections:

```
var params = _.extend({
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': this.url,
    'cache': true,
    'dataType': 'json',
    'processData': true
}, options);

console.log(params);

return $.ajax(params);
```

I am unable to find out what is wrong.

Working version with 0.9.9

```
http://92.245.6.92/backbone.peoples/index.html
```

Upgraded and not working version with 0.9.10

```
http://92.245.6.92/backbone.peoples/index2.html
```

Could you please help me whether there is major fault in my code or what happened. 0.9.10 is release candidate for 1.0 so I expect this not to work with any new version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fetch `success` callback signatures was changed from `0.9.9` to `0.9.10`. The callback signature is now

```
function(collection, resp, options) { ...
```

In your app you've overridden `Collection.sync`, and you execute the callback with (`app.js:35`):

```
options.success = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    model.parse(data);
    if(success)
        success(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
};
```

This leads to a situation where Backbone tries to call a method `reset` on the `data` object, which is a vanilla javascript array and doesn't have such a method.
To comply to the new API, you need to call it with:

```
var collection = this;
options.success = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    model.parse(data);
    if(success)
        success(collection , data, options);
};
```

Comment: @Kato there's multiple breaking changes in the `0.9.x` patch series. It's annoying and not very `semver`-ish, but at the same time when the major version is `0` you should expect some fluctuation. I for one commend the Backbone team for not stagnating on bad APIs for not wanting to break existing code. They're gearing for a 1.0, and now if ever is the time to clear up old crud. If the same cycle continues after 1.0 then I agree with you.